# Como enviar el id a un modal

Tags: php

```
   <table id="example" class="display" style="width:100%">
                        <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Id</th>
                            <th>Producto</th>
                            <th>Precio</th>
                            <th>Marca</th>
                            <th>
                        </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                        @foreach ($productos as $producto)

                            <tr>
                                <td>{{$producto->id}}</td>
                                <td>{{$producto->producto}}</td>
                                <td>{{$producto->precio}}</td>
                                <td>{{$producto->marca}}</td>
                                <td>


                                    <a  class="btn btn-primary btn-group-sm col-lg-offset-2 active"
                                       data-toggle="modal" href="#modal-eliminar{{$producto->id}}"
                                       > <i class="fa fa-trash"></i>
                                    </a>
                                </td>
                        @endforeach
                        </tbody>

                    </table>
```

**Este es mi modal donde recibo el parámetro el problema que tengo
es que si me detecta el id que selecciono pero entonces no me habré el modal 
si quito {{$producto->id}} del href y del modal que lo recibe ahi si me abre**

```
<div class="modal fade" id="modal-eliminar{{$producto->id }}" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel"
     aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header text-center">
                <h4 class="modal-title w-100 font-weight-bold">Productos Eliminar</h4>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body mx-6">
```

Answer (score 0):

Creo que para pasar datos al modal deberías usar data-target="#modal-eliminar" dentro del la etiqueta  en vez de usar href y pasarle los datos a través de data-datos , de la siguiente manera:

```
<a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal-eliminar" data-datos="datosapasar" data-datos2="pasarotrosdatos"> Mi link</a>
```

Posteriormente podemos tratar estos datos pasados con jquery y asignarselos a cualquier campo del modal:

```
$('#modal-eliminar').on('show.bs.modal', function (event) {
        var etiqueta = $(event.relatedTarget)
        var recipient = etiqueta.data('datos')
        var recipient2 = etiqueta.data('datos2')

        var modal = $(this)
        //Guardamos el resultado en un input dentro del modal de nombre mnombre
        modal.find('.modal-body #mnombre').val(recipient)
   })
```

Un saludo

Answer (score 0):

Solo hay un modal, así que su `id` debe ser `id="modal-eliminar"`, independientemente del artículo que se vaya a eliminar.

Lo que te faltaría es indicarle (mediante javascript) en el momento de pulsar, cual es el `id` que se ha pulsado.

Podría ser algo como:

En el botón, añadimos una clase `product_del`, para añadirle el evento `click` y un atributo personalizado `data-product_id` con el valor del `id` del producto asociado al  botón.

```
<a  class="btn btn-primary btn-group-sm col-lg-offset-2 active product_del"
    data-toggle="modal" href="#modal-eliminar" data-product_id="{{$producto->id}}"
    > <i class="fa fa-trash"></i>
</a>
```

en javascript añadimos el evento 'click':

```
$('.product_del').click(function (event) {
    var id = $(event.target).data('product_id');
    // faltaría asignar el id a algún elemento del modal
    // actualmente el modal esta vacío y no hace nada 
});
```